# null converting to 0.00 delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac

I inherited a program that copies all the info from one DB table into a different DB. The program was written in delphi 7 i believe and was using IDAC. Once I got it I converted updated it to Delphi 10.1 and moved it over to use FireDac. The issue I am having is in the original table it has fields with null values. When I move it over to the other DB it converts it from a null to 0.00. In the original program this did not happen and I cannot find anything in the code to tell it to do this. Does anyone have any idea how to have it insert the null instead of converting it.

Comment: It's not clear and too broad, but a guess, the column could have a `DEFAULT` value which is 0. You don't even post some code (at least how did you insert the data) also if you change the data mapping for FireDAC or not.

Comment: It is more of a broad question. It is a very large program that moves over many tables from one db to another. It did not convert them with IDAC but now does with FireDac so i was just wondering if there was a something simple I was missing here. I can absolutely fix this with code but if there is a simple setting that I am unaware of that would be much easier

Comment: Is the definition of the database tables the same in the new and in the old database? Databases can be definied so that a value in a column becomes a default value when assigned null. Do you dynamically create the table in the target database from your code? If yes, then show that code. If no, then check the definition of the table in the target database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your (or FireDAC's) code, the field's value is being handled as an integer-type value.

You can avoid this behaviour by doing a field-by-field copy along the following lines:

```
  var
    SourceField,
    DestField : TField;
    i : Integer;
  begin
    [...]
    for i := 0 to SourceTable.FieldCount - 1 do begin
      SourceField := SourceTable.Fields[i];
      DestField := DestTable.Fields[i];
      if SourceField.IsNull then
        DestField.Clear  //  Sets DestField to Null
      else
        DestField.Value := SourceField.Value;
    end;
    [...]
  end;
```

This assumes that the source- and destination-tables have the same structure, of course and that the fields are all non-blob types.  Any blob field needs to be copied by the field's calling LoadFromStream and SaveToStream methods.

Comment: I was wrong it did not fix the issue. When i do it this and see what updated in the DB grid the fields that are supposed to be null are blank and do not have a 0.00 in them anymore. Good sign! but when I pull the record up in the DB is shows 0.00 and not null. Now I am at a loss

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "pull the record up in the DB"?  What control is displaying the "0.00"?

Comment: @Shea if your records on the grid are null, then they are null in the database. The problem of showing a 0.00 when pulling a record is in your code pulling that value. Can you show us that code ?. Please notice that there is a difference in how you access your fields in Delphi 7 and FireDAC. On FireDAC a MyFireDACField.Value is converted to integer (like in MyD7Field.AsInteger), and if you want to get a null you have to retrieve it as MyFireDACField.AsVariant (which is the equivalent of the MyD7Field.Value).

Answer (score 0):

Change all the references of (SomeField)**.Value** to (SomeField)**.AsVariant** in your code. Because in FireDAC **.Value** is converted to integer/float/string/... (as **.AsInteger** did in Delphi 7), so your null values are converted to 0.00.

@MartynA's code will now be :

```
 var
    SourceField,
    DestField : TField;
    i : Integer;
  begin
    [...]
    for i := 0 to SourceTable.FieldCount - 1 do begin
      SourceField := SourceTable.Fields[i];
      DestField := DestTable.Fields[i];
      DestField.AsVariant := SourceField.AsVariant;
    end;
    [...]
  end;
```

And any further access to the fields values do it through the **.AsVariant** method, so null values are not read as 0.

Comment: So it this works and what MartynA suggested works too but what is happening is the null is being inserted but is then somehow being changed to a 0 after the post. I verified this by putting a few showmessages in and everything came back showing it was null but when I refresh the dbgrid or look at the record in winSQL it is showing 0. Something else in my program must be changing it after the post but nothing else is called after the post. I am at a real loss with this one

Comment: It doesn't really gets changed, on the database it always is a null, but when you read it on FireDAC using the .Value method, it uses a default value of 0 when the value is null, if you want to behave like Delphi 7 (no default value) then you need to switch to the .AsVariant method. The reason is because now .Value doesn't return a Variant but an Integer, String, Float, ..., and those type can't be null so they need to use a default value.